# How to add a child component in Angular2 Javascript (no typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a hello world program running in Angular2 RC5 without typescript. The first component loads without errors, but I can't get a child component to load. I get no errors--the child component content just doesn't render/display.

I also can't figure out how to put it up on plunkr or codepen, since there appears to be no CDNs for RCs.  The 'npm install' version is at https://github.com/dolthead/ng2js.

```js
// app.module.js
(function (app) {

    app.AppModule =
        ng.core.NgModule({
            imports: [ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule],
            declarations: [app.AppComponent, app.InputListComponent],
            bootstrap: [app.AppComponent]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
            }
        });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platformBrowserDynamic
            .platformBrowserDynamic()
            .bootstrapModule(app.AppModule);
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));

// app.component.js
(function (app) {

    app.AppComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
            imports: [app.InputListComponent],
            directives: [
              app.InputListComponent, // child component
              ng.common.FORM_DIRECTIVES] // for ngModel
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
            }
        });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));

// input-list.component.js - the child component
(function (app) {

    app.InputListComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'input-list',
            templateUrl: 'app/input-list.component.html'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
                console.log('input-list constructor');
                var self = this;
                self.status = '';
                self.statusList = [];

                self.addStatus = function() {
                    self.statusList.push(this.status);
                    this.status = '';
                }
            }
        });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Could you include some code about what you have working?

Comment: What is the browser you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest Chrome release...on a mac...running from WebStorm.

Comment: It worked here on Firefox. I can see an input and an update button.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it from that angle and see what's incompatible in Chrome.

Comment: When you find an answer, please post it here. It will be very important for the community.

Comment: For sure. Updated to rc6 and trying to get it running with ngModule declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got ng-model working with RC6 (js, no ts). Add the forms module to index.html:

`<script src="node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js"></script>`

And import the FormsModule in the NgModule meta data:

```
// app.module.js
(function (app) {

    app.AppModule =
        ng.core.NgModule({
            imports: [
                ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule,
                ng.forms.FormsModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                app.AppComponent,
                app.InputListComponent
            ],
            providers: [],
            bootstrap: [app.AppComponent]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function AppModule() {
            }
        });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platformBrowserDynamic
            .platformBrowserDynamic()
            .bootstrapModule(app.AppModule);
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));

// app.component.js
(function (app) {

    app.AppComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
            imports: [app.InputListComponent]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
            }
        });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));

// input-list.component.js - the child component
(function (app) {

    app.InputListComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'input-list',
            templateUrl: 'app/input-list.component.html'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
                console.log('input-list constructor');
                var self = this;
                self.status = '';
                self.statusList = [];

                self.addStatus = function() {
                    self.statusList.push(this.status);
                    this.status = '';
                }
            }
        });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: And it runs in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks again to @richard for getting past the first hurdle, and Mirko Nasato for his reply in his Angular2 Udemy course https://www.udemy.com/angular-2-from-the-ground-up/learn/v4/content.